# "GitHub Could not create service hooks subscription" Display when trying to add pull request on CI

Tags: github, azure-devops

Trting to add branch on Pull request trigger on Azure Devops but it does not work It shows "GitHub Could not create service hooks subscription".
[image]

[image]